# Chrome Extensions to focus the first input field?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox-extensions, google-chrome-extensions

I am looking for this [Firefox extension](http://firstfield.mozdev.org/) called FirstField, but for Chrome. Essentially, you press a keyboard shortcut and it focuses the first text input field on the webpage (for example, the Wikipedia search). How difficult would it be to create this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick search for *focus* on the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/) brought up [Input Focus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hdpcnibgpokgegmjefjickphdnhhniol?hl=en). It looks like it will do what you want, press Ctrl+Alt+L to set focus on a page's first text field and then press the combo again to start cycling through whatever other text fields are on the page.

Comment: Extension is no longer available (404) :-(

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking for something even more comprehensive, I've been super happy with the [Vimium Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb?hl=en) which is especially fluid if you know a bit of VI(M), but useful even if not.

If you install Vimium, you can snag the first input field by typing `gi`

You can then tab to other text entry fields.

Alternatively, you can prefix `gi` with a numeral, as in `3gi`, which will start you on the third visible entry field.

As an additional alternative, you can type `f` which will give all the clickable links & elements (including text entry fields) on the page a short keyboard command (e.g. `MN`). You can then type this short stroke to jump focus there.

Comment: A perhaps important addition is that the tab and jump stuff I've described seem to only work for elements that are currently visible on the page (ie visible to the user based on scroll position). It does not appear possible to tab to text input fields that are off screen, so one would need to first scroll (Vimium has some handy shortcuts for this) and then do gi

Answer (score 1):

You can install [TamperMonkey](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo).

Open the **Dashboard** and click the `+` sign to add a new script.

This code focuses the first input on all websites on document load:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Focus Input Global
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        *://*/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==


(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Your code here...
    document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].focus();
})();
```

Explanation:

1. The `// @match    *://*/*` is the URL pattern that matches the pages you want your script to run on, in this case `*://*/*` means all pages.
2. This line `document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].focus();` finds all input elements in the document using `getElementsByTagName('input')` and then focuses on the first one `[0]` using `.focus()`.

---

If the `// @match    *://*/*` doesn't work on some page, then create a new script targeting that specific page, ex: `// @match    https://www.google.com/*`.

If the `[0]` doesn't work for a specific page, ex: `// @match    https://www.google.com/*`, then try incrementing numbers to select the targeted input, `[1]`,`[2]`...

If the `getElementsByTagName` doesn't work, then you can use one of the following:

- `document.getElementsByName('search')[0].focus();`
- `document.getElementsByClassName('form-control')[0].focus();`
- `document.getElementById('id').focus();`

> Find the target element **name**, **class** or **id** in DevTools.

If the `.focus()` doesn't work, then you can try with `.click()`.

---

If you want to trigger the focus with a keyboard shortcut `Ctrl + Shift + L` for ex `google.com`, then put this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Focus Input Google Key Combo
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.google.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Your code here...
    document.onkeydown = function (e) {
        // Detect if Ctrl + Shift is pressed together
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey) {
            // Detect if L is pressed after Ctrl + Shift
            if (e.key == "L")
            {
                // Focus Input Element
                document.getElementsByName('q')[0].focus();
                document.getElementsByName('q')[0].select();
            }
        }
    };
})();
```

The `.select()` selects the input field value if you have previously something typed in.

Read more about [keyboard combinations](https://daily-dev-tips.com/posts/javascript-detecting-key-combinations/)