# is there a way to make Google Chrome to focus only on text fields when pressing tab?

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

is there a way (setting, or extension) to make tabbing on Google Chrome (at least on Mac OS X) to focus only on text fields, instead of all focusable elements? That is, let's say the focus in on the omnibar now, I'd like to hit `tab` on keyboard once and have it focus on the first text field in the web page. Currently it would first go through all the bookmarks in the bookmark bar, then all web page elements (mostly links). I found that this behavior very counter-intuitive, and is different from other browsers that I am familiar with.

In System Preferences, I have already set "Full Keyboard Access" to "Text boxes and lists only". Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a setting in Chrome now:

Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Web Content -> Uncheck "Pressing Tab on a webpage highlights links, as well as form fields"

Answer (score 1):

There are two Chrome extensions that may help you.

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/308990/138239) suggests checking out an extension called [Input Focus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hdpcnibgpokgegmjefjickphdnhhniol?hl=en)

From [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/540687/138239) to that [same question](https://superuser.com/q/308930/138239):

> If you're looking for something even more comprehensive, I've been
>   super happy with the
>   [Vimium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb?hl=en)
>   Chrome Extension which is especially fluid if you know a bit of VI(M),
>   but useful even if not.
>
> If you install Vimium, you can snag the first input field by typing
>   `gi`
>
> You can then tab to other text entry fields.

Comment: I couldn't get Input Focus to install; it seems like at least one other reviewer had the same problem.

Comment: with Vimium, `gi` goes to the first text field, but you can't tab to other text fields... it goes to other html elements (e.g, links).

Comment: Hmm, it seems that the behavior for Vimium (at least for me) is that gi will go to first visible field (ie part of the page you can currently see based on scroll) and, if more than one entry box is visible, tab will cycle through them. However, if one (or no) text entry fields are visible, perhaps you'll get the tab behavior you're describing.